# Safari Mobile and Twitter Bootstrap not showing images

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

I have a website using html + twitter bootstrap + angularjs and it works fine in desktop's browsers - even when I resize the window. In iphones however, using safari mobile, the images on this markup don't appear.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="orderBy('Group.Name')" class="clickable">{{'_GroupLabel_' | i18n}}</th>
            <th ng-click="orderBy('FirstName')" class="clickable">{{'_FirstNameLabel_' | i18n}}</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:orderByPredicate:orderReverse">
            <td><a ng-href="#/home/list/{{user.Group.Id}}">{{user.Group.Name}}</a></td>
            <td><a ng-href="#/home/list/{{user.Id}}">{{user.FirstName}}&nbsp;{{user.LastName}}</a></td>
            <td>
                <span ng-show="user.RoleId == 1">
                    <span ng-switch="user.TodaysRecord != null" class="clickable">
                        <span ng-switch-when="true"
                              navigate-to="/manage/record/create/{{user.Id}}/{{user.TodaysRecord.Id}}">
                         ==>   <img ng-show="user.TodaysRecord.Sent" src="~/img/todo-list-sent.jpg"
                                 title="Sent today at {{user.LatestUpdate | date:'MMM d, y HH:mm'}}" />
                          ==>   <img ng-show="user.TodaysRecord.Sent == false" src="~/img/todo-list-partial.jpg"
                                 title="Not sent yet" />
                        </span>
                          ==>  <img src="~/img/todo-list.jpg" ng-switch-when="false" title="ToDo"
                             navigate-to="/manage/record/create/{{user.Id}}" />
                    </span>
                     ==> <img class="clickable" src="~/img/sleep.jpg" title="Sleep time" ng-click="addRecordProperty(user, 'sleepTimes')" />
                      ==> <img class="clickable" src="~/img/toilet.jpg" title="Nappy/Toilet time" ng-click="addRecordProperty(user, 'toiletTimes')" />
                </span>
               ==>   <img class="clickable" src="~/img/edit.jpg" title="Edit" ng-click="edit(user)" />
            ==>      <img class="clickable" src="~/img/bin.jpg" title="Delete" ng-click="delete(user)" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing `~`?

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is a [known signalR behavior](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1406) on iOS.